# how to define full text searching on table with two keys?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table with 2 columns as primary key like below.

```
create table table1(key1 int NOT NULL,key2 int NOT NULL,content NVARCHAR(MAX), primary key(key1,key2))
```

I have created index on table with this query

```
CREATE unique INDEX index1 ON table1 (key1,key2);
```

and with this query, I create full-text searching

```
create fulltext index on table1 (content ) key index index1;
```

but I get this error because index must be single-column

> 'index1' is not a valid index to enforce a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique, non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, does not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full-text key.

and with single Column indexing, when I insert a new row I get a duplicate error.

what should I do?

I am using SQL Server and EF orm

### Update

i solve this problem by creating a computed column that return unique data

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD indexKey  AS cast(key1 as float) + cast((cast(key2 as float)/power(10,len(key2))) as float) PERSISTED not null
```

and i create my index on this column and it work pretty fine.

Comment: You do NOT have two primary keys. That is actually impossible. What you have is a composite primary key which means your primary key consists of two (or more) columns.

Comment: i edit the question.

Comment: The documentation and the error message are quite clear. The key index must be a single column. If you want to create a full-text index, you will need to modify your table and add a single column that will be unique. It does  not need to be the primary key, though some would argue otherwise. It could be an identity column. While you are changing things, you might as well make the content column not null since it makes no sense to allow null values.

Comment: that will be an unnecessary column , i want to create a computed column from two keys but i can't